# Why is output of MaxHeapSze different when calling -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal and -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags?

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

Just like the question, when I run the program with JVM option -XX+PrintFlagsFinal, I can see the printed MaxHeapSize as below:

```
 bool MaxFDLimit                                = true            {product}
uintx MaxGCMinorPauseMillis                     = 4294967295      {product}
uintx MaxGCPauseMillis                          = 4294967295      {product}
uintx MaxHeapFreeRatio                          = 70              {product}
**uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1044381696      {product}**
 intx MaxInlineLevel                            = 9               {product}
 intx MaxInlineSize                             = 35              {product}
 intx MaxJavaStackTraceDepth                    = 1024            {product}
```

While when I run the same program with JVM option -XX+PrintCommandLineFlags, I can see the MaxHeapSize as :

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=65192896 **-XX:MaxHeapSize=1043086336** -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Can you tell me why these two are different? I thought they should be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual heap size may differ from what the user specified in the command line due to alignment and ergonomics adjustments. By default, the heap is 2MB aligned ([see collectorPolicy.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/memory/collectorPolicy.cpp#l174)).

1044381696 is the final heap size after 2MB-alignment of 1043086336.

Comment: Thanks. But (1044381696-1043086336) is around 1.23M, not 2M. What do you think about it?

Comment: @PixelsTech 1043086336 is not 2M-aligned, i.e. X / (2*1024*1024) = 497.38 - fractional. The nearest multiple of 2M to it is 1044381696: X / (2*1024*1024) = 498.