# Clarification of meaning new JVM memory parameters InitialRAMPercentage and MinRAMPercentage

Tags: java, docker, jvm

Reference: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8186315

I'm really struggling to find out what MinRAMPercentage does, especially compared to InitialRAMPercentage.

I assumed that InitialRAMPercentage sets the amount of heap at startup, that MinRAMPercentage and MaxRAMPercentage set the bottom and top limit of heap that the JVM is allowed to shrink/grow to.

Apparently that is not the case. When I start a JVM (with UseContainerSupport, having these new memory setting parameters) like so:

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=40.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=20.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep Heap
```

InitialHeap and MaxHeap get set, there is no "Minimum Heap Size" value that I can find; Consequently, that MinRAMPercentage never seems to get used.

Super confused, and apparently, I'm not the only one; the OpenJ9 dudes seem to also not fully parse the intent of these options, as I've gathered [here](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/1428) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/pull/1699). They seem to have opted to simply not implement MinRAMPercentage afaics.

So: What is the real intended usage and effect of setting MinRAMPercentage?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`-XX:InitialRAMPercentage` is used to [calculate initial heap size](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/file/a7f53869e42b/src/hotspot/share/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1816) when `InitialHeapSize` / `-Xms` is not set.

It sounds counterintuitive, but both `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` and `-XX:MinRAMPercentage` are used to calculate *maximum heap size* when `MaxHeapSize` / `-Xmx` is not set:

- For systems with small physical memory `MaxHeapSize` is estimated as

  ```
  phys_mem * MinRAMPercentage / 100  (if this value is less than 96M)
  ```
- Otherwise (non-small physical memory) `MaxHeapSize` is estimated as

  ```
  MAX(phys_mem * MaxRAMPercentage / 100, 96M)
  ```

[The exact formula](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/file/a7f53869e42b/src/hotspot/share/runtime/arguments.cpp#l1750) is a bit more complicated as it also takes other factors into account.

Note: the algorithm for calculating initial and maximum heap size depends on the particular JVM version. The preferred way to control the heap size is to set `Xmx` and `Xms` explicitly.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071798/what-is-the-difference-between-xmx-and-maxram-jvm-parameters).

Comment: How you explain this?
Command:
```sudo docker run --memory='10m' adoptopenjdk/openjdk11 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize```
Result:
```Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport
size_t MaxHeapSize = 8388608 {product} {ergonomic}
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11+28, mixed mode)``` 

According your explanation MaxHeapSize should be 5M not 8M

Comment: @MichałMielec As I've told, there are other factors, such as [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228242/3448419) and [default generation sizes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gc_globals.hpp#l703). They come on stage when the memory limit is so small.

Comment: Isn't InitialHeapSize/MaxHeapSize always set and used as Xms/Xms if they are not provided explicitly?

Comment: @freakman Not sure I understand what you mean. Please ask a separate question, describe your problem and provide an example.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why are there separate MinRAMPercentage and MaxRAMPercentage? What's the point of separating memory to 2 range of below and above 100 MB?

Comment: What the purpose to set InitialRAMPercentage if we set MaxRAMPercentage or  MinRAMPercentage ? I suppose the jvm will automatically increase memory usage to reach MaxRAMPercentage so we need to set InitialRAMPercentage ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your container memory also, So lets suppose you have container memory as 1 GB then in this case -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80 will be used to determine the max heap ~ 800mb heap memory will be used

And suppose you have container memory less than 250mb then -XX:MinRAMPercentage=20.0 will be used ~ 50mb heap memory will be used

use this article to understand more [XX:MinRAMPercentage,XX:MaxRAMPercentage](https://blog.gceasy.io/2020/11/05/difference-between-initialrampercentage-minrampercentage-maxrampercentage/)