# why MaxRAMPercentage is lower than MinRAMPercentage?

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to figure out how to use more resources inside docker container, starting from java 8 update 191 there are new flags which I believe are supossed to let us configure to use more than 1/4 of available ram. Anyway, why default values for those flags are so strange? Max is 25.0 where Min is 50.0? How does it work?

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)

java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxRAMPercentage
double MaxRAMPercentage                          = 25.000000

java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MinRAMPercentage
double MinRAMPercentage                          = 50.000000
```

Comment: Same defaults on Windows, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297753/2711488