# OpenJDK MaxRAMPercentage on a machine with very large amount of memory

Tags: java, openjdk-11

When running OpenJDK 11 on a machine with 60GB of memory (and more), the 
`MaxRAMPercentage` only allows me to allocate up to around 30GB.

This works correctly:

```
>~# java   -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=10 -XshowSettings:vm -version
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 5.90G
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1bpo91)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1bpo91, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But when the percentage should produce a heap size above 30G, I get:

```
>~# java   -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75 -XshowSettings:vm -version
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 29.97G
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1bpo91)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian-1bpo91, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Using good old `-Xmx` works (e.g. `-Xmx50G`).

What am I missing? Is `MaxRAMPercentage` supposed to be bounded?

Comment: This bug may be related : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213175

Comment: Perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297753/3301492) might be helpful.

Comment: @Arnaud, thanks, that was indeed the problem. Would you like to put this as an answer so I can vote it up?

Comment: Well @daphshez, that was just a hint and I don't know how it is fixed/workarounded. If it is clearer for you, don't hesitate to answer your own question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is a bug/feature related to [CompressedOops](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops) (CompressedOops limits the heap size to 32GB, and while `-Xmx` disables CompressedOops, `MaxRAMPercentage` doesn't).

To solve / workaround you can either:

- Add `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` to disable CompressedOops
- Use OpenJDK13, where the bug is fixed

The bug report is [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213175). HT @Arnaud for directing me there.