# Docker - Java container doesn't respect memory limits

Tags: java, docker, memory, docker-compose, jvm

I've been reading multiple posts regarding limiting the container's JVM memory, nothing has worked so far, I don't know where I am messing up.

I made a simple "Hello World" in Spring Boot, using a REST controller, it has nothing else.

Such app was exported as a WAR file, running it with the Tomcat JDK 11 image, I can also run it using the JDK image with a FatJar but the problem persists either way.

---

**Expected**

Have my Java container not take more than 25 MB memory (for the sake of a number, could be more)

**Actual**

Such a simple application is taking 200 - 250 MB memory in `docker stats`

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.30-jdk11-corretto
COPY tomcat.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    hello:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: app-test
        environment:
            - JVM_OPTS=-Xms13m -Xmx25m
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

---

**I have tried**

-Xms13m -Xmx25m

-XX:PermSize=13m -XX:MaxPermSize=25m

*Among other flags that I already deleted and forgot about*

Comment: `-Xms13m -Xmx25m` is only for JVM menory not for the container.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Oh, does that mean my flags are working but I also have to limit the container in another way?

Comment: I really doubt a standard JVM will start with such limited memory (unless you're using some micro edition).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It was merely an example, isn't 250MB too much for a simple Hello World? I can't imagine setting up multiple microservices this way

Comment: Take a look at [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) (hence my *non-standard* comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restrict memory for docker containers, you need to add following in your docker-compose.yml file

```
environment:
  - <name>=<value>
deploy:
  resources:
    memory: 256M
```

Once you add the above code, then containers would be restricted to given memory limit and you can see the result in `docker stats` output. For more details about the resource restriction refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) docker documentation.

> **Note**: If the container crosses the given memory limit, the kernel will kill the container.

Comment: That was it, I also changed the image to openjdk 11 slim, it actually made a difference, the Hello World is only taking 90M

Comment: @Jouo I'm glad it helped. In docker, choosing base image wisely is important.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable that tomcat's catalina.sh script depends on for java options is : JAVA_OPTS.
If you change the compose file to use the following env variable , it should work.

`environment:
  - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Xms128m`

Apart from the fact that 25m seems a way too less memory for a JVM with tomcat running.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how little memory you set for JVM heap (-Xmx) there are lots of other types of non-heap memory that JVM uses: [Java using much more memory than heap size (or size correctly Docker memory limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438) - you need to take that into account.

You can also avoid setting -Xmx altogether and instead leverage -XX:MaxRAMPercentage: [Clarification of meaning new JVM memory parameters InitialRAMPercentage and MinRAMPercentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292282/clarification-of-meaning-new-jvm-memory-parameters-initialrampercentage-and-minr/54297753#54297753)