# Wrong Heap size is obtained when using different values for MinRAMPercentage and MaxRAM Percentage

Tags: java, kubernetes, heap-memory, heap-size

I have a 1 GB container with Memory Limit = 1 GiB in K8S.

I am using Java SUSE.

I am setting the MinRAMPercentage and MaxRAMPercentage values as follows:

```
bash-4.4# java -server -XX:MinRAMPercentage=64 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=100 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings -version 2>&1 | grep ' MaxHeapSize'
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 687865856                                 {product} {ergonomic}
bash-4.4# java -server -XX:MinRAMPercentage=65 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=100 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings -version 2>&1 | grep ' MaxHeapSize'
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 1073741824                                {product} {ergonomic}
```

Since the Container < 1.3 GiB MinRAMPercentage should be used as configuring paramater, MaxRAMPercentage shall be ignored.

But when looking at Min = 64, Max = 100 actually the MinRAMPercentage value is used which is correct.

When having Min 64 and Max 100 then the MaxRAMPercentage value is used which is not correct.

This behavior happens for different combinations of Min/Max and also is dependent on container Limit, i.e. for a different container Limit these values behaves differently.

I've done a lot of measurement to find out the behavior of the JVM.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Did you read the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297753/6250649 ?
Any reason why you do not want to set -Xmx explicitly? Possibly through JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

Comment: Thanks for answering.Yes, I want to use the percentages instead to align that the heap size will follow the container limit.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My project wants to use percentages instead in order to follow the changes of the value of the Container Limit.