# JVM does not allocate all memory that is defined with -Xmx argument

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I have a jar file that i run with a `systemd` unit file. The run command in the unit file is the following:

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xms200m -Xmx465m --enable-preview -jar
> myapp-1.0.0.jar

My application always logs the maximum amount of RAM it is allowed to use. It logs this using the following code:

```
public static int ONE_MEGABYTE_IN_BYTES = 1048576;
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
int maximumJVMHeapAllocation = Math.round(runtime.maxMemory() / oneMegabyteInBytes);
```

For some reason the value of `runtime.maxMemory()` is always about `15mb` less then the value of the `-Xmx` argument. So if the jar file is run with the argument `-Xmx465m` then the application will only get `450mb` of usable RAM memory.

My question is: What is the remaining 15 mb of `RAM` used for? Is the used for stack memory?

EDIT: To avoid confusion; The total amount of RAM available to the server is `1GB`. `512MB` of that is used by the operating system `Amazon Linux 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, JVM runs with Parallel or Serial GC, where the Young Generation of the heap consists of Eden and two Survivor spaces (see [Generations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/generations.html)).

JVM keeps one of Survivor spaces empty: an application cannot use both simultaneously. Therefore, `Runtime.maxMemory` excludes the size of one Survivor space (which seems to be 15 MB in your case).

Other GC algorithms behave differently. For example, if you run JVM with `-XX:+UseG1GC`, the maximum available memory as shown by `Runtime.maxMemory` will be equal to `-Xmx` (more precisely, it'll be 466 MB because of the [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228242/3448419)).